# customicing django admin interface

Tags: python, django

As you know the backend, admin site shows the models, that includes by default Users and then the others that you may have added in the admin.py file.

You can also see that the Users interface has filtering controls, namely a search text field on the top, and filtering variables on a panel on the right. That comes by default for Users.

But you can get those controls too for your own models by doing something like this:

In your model add:

```
class Admin:
        list_display = ('post', 'name', 'created_at')
        list_filter = ('keyword', 'name', 'created_at')
        ordering = ('created_at', )
        search_fields = ('trackword', )
```

so those, list_display, list_filter, search_fields will be your filtering controls. However, I have done that and I get none of them in the Admin backend. I surely am missing something I should have added, but I have followed the instructions of a book and I do as they say.

I am using the latest django, 2.01

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there.
You have to register your model to be used in the admin panel such as:

```
class ModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('post', 'name', 'created_at')
        list_filter = ('keyword', 'name', 'created_at')
        ordering = ('created_at', )
        search_fields = ('trackword', )
admin.site.register(ModelName, ModelNameAdmin)
```

The "Admin" class has to inherit from admin.ModelAdmin and you have to register it by passing the model and modeladmin class.

Alternativly you could use a decorator:

```
@admin.register(ModelName)
class ModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

[Check the Django docs here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: Aita! Tere tulemaast kalis Klient!